# Midi MediaElement support in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, streaming, midi

I am trying to build a small silverlight application to support some midi files as well. I've tried using the Media element, but I don't think that it can read midi files. Does any of you know a workaround, without the need to convert the midi file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't support MIDI. There are a few ways you could handle this:

- Decode the MIDI (using something like [MIDI Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx)) and synthesize the audio using a custom [MediaStreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource(VS.95).aspx).
- Decode the MIDI and use it to trigger MP3 samples.
- Include another control in the page which can play MIDI, such as the Windows Media Player control.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response. Two questions though, Is is a silverlight xaml element such as windows media player for me to customly change?

How much work do you reckon it would be to create my own MediaStreamSource for midi resources?

Thanks